# Microsoft Graph API Access Token Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm having an issue getting an access token through Postman.

I'm following this process "Flow 2". 
http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/

**"Flow 1" worked for me.**

This is the given scenario. I am sending a post request with body.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/e0xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx09d53164/oauth2/v2.0/token

{

client_id:id

client_secret:secret

grant_type:password

username:user

password:pass

scope:openid

}

Response -> "AADSTS90002: Tenant ' ' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.

Why would the Tenant be blank given it was populated?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you send is wrong. This parameter should not be `AAD_name`, but `tenant`.

Try this:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=xxxxx
&scope=openid
&username=user
&password=pass
&grant_type=password
```

You could find your `tenant` in App registrations:
[image]

For more information, you could see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc).

---

If you want to use `{{AAD_name}}`, you need to set `Environment` in postman firstly.

[image]

Then you could send the post request like the [link](http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/) shows.

Comment: I'm using the literal tenant id in the URL. Replacing AAD_name. Still getting the same error

Comment: @Jack.c Check your `username`, make sure its format is like `xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com`.